# Router and redirect in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am a beginner in react.
I'm trying to set up router and rendering to change pages but it gives me errors that I can't understand.

I have installed to terminal `npm install react-router-dom`
in my `index.js` I have import `BrowserRouter` and embedded my APP

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom"

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

In my `app.js` I have import route switch from `react-router-dom`.

```
import Home from './page/home';
import Authentication from "./page/authentication";
import Header from './componenti/header';
import './App.css';
import DashboardComponent from './page/dashboardComponent';
import {Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom"

function App(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header/>
      <Switch>        
          <Route exact path="/" render={(props)=> <Home/>}/>
          <Route exact path="authentication" render={(props)=> <Authentication/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/dashboard-component" render={(props)=> <DashboardComponent/>}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Very similar is the redirect, in my authentication page I imported the redirect from `react-router-dom` but it is not correct.

```
import styles from '../style/authentication.module.css';
import {useState} from "react";
import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom"

const Authentication = () => {

--- other code ---

    let postLoginRedirect = null;
    if (isLogged) {
    return postLoginRedirect = <Redirect to="/dashboardComponent"/>
    }
    return(
    <div>
    
    </div>
    )
}
export default Authentication
```

It seems to me everything is correct, I read a lot about this topic, I copied the solution from web app developed by me with react, but it doesn't work, I don't understand.

this is the error message:

ERROR in ./src/App.js 18:35-41

> export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in
> 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: BrowserRouter, HashRouter, Link,
> MemoryRouter, NavLink, Navigate, Outlet, Route, Router, Routes,
> UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext,
> createRoutesFromChildren, createSearchParams, generatePath, matchPath,
> matchRoutes, renderMatches, resolvePath, unstable_HistoryRouter,
> useHref, useInRouterContext, useLinkClickHandler, useLocation,
> useMatch, useNavigate, useNavigationType, useOutlet, useOutletContext,
> useParams, useResolvedPath, useRoutes, useSearchParams)

ERROR in ./src/page/authentication.js 48:52-60

> export 'Redirect' (imported as 'Redirect') was not found in
> 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: BrowserRouter, HashRouter, Link,
> MemoryRouter, NavLink, Navigate, Outlet, Route, Router, Routes,
> UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext,
> createRoutesFromChildren, createSearchParams, generatePath, matchPath,
> matchRoutes, renderMatches, resolvePath, unstable_HistoryRouter,
> useHref, useInRouterContext, useLinkClickHandler, useLocation,
> useMatch, useNavigate, useNavigationType, useOutlet, useOutletContext,
> useParams, useResolvedPath, useRoutes, useSearchParams)

Comment: switch is coming from package called  `react-router`

`import { Route, Switch } from "react-router";`

Comment: which version of router dom you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all the `react-router-dom` tutorials out there are outdated and still refer to the `react-router-dom@5` API spec.

It looks like you've accidentally upgraded/installed the latest version of `react-router-dom`, version 6. You've two options from here:

1. Downgrade/revert back to version v5.x

   Uninstall any current versions of `react-router-dom` and `react-dom`, and then install a specific v5 version of them.

   From your project directory run:

   - ```
     npm un -s react-router-dom react-dom
     ```
   - ```
     npm i -s react-router-dom@5 react-dom@5
     ```
2. Complete/apply the v5 migration guide

   [Upgrading from v5](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5)

   If you decide to move forward with the migration then you'll likely want to uninstall `react-router` since `react-router-dom` re-exports all the exports from `react-router`, or at a minimum you want to ensure it's on the same version.

   Uninstall:

   ```
   npm un -s react-router
   ```

   Or reinstall latest of each:

   - ```
     npm un -s react-router-dom react-router
     ```
   - ```
     npm i -s react-router-dom@latest
     ```

   App

   ```
   import {Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom"

   function App(props) {
     return (
       <div>
         <Header />
         <Routes>        
           <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
           <Route path="authentication" element={<Authentication />} />
           <Route path="/dashboard-component" element={<DashboardComponent />} />
         </Routes>
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```

   Authentication

   ```
   const Authentication = () => {

     --- other code ---

     let postLoginRedirect = null;
     if (isLogged) {
       return <Navigate to="/dashboardComponent" replace />;
     }
     return(
       <div>
         ...
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `react-router-dom` **v6** you should do replace `Switch` with `Routes`

```
import {Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useNavigate` hook from React Router. From the ([docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate)):

> The useNavigate hook returns a function that lets you navigate programmatically, for example in an effect:

Usage:

```js
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate("/somepage");
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Navigate to redirect **in React 18**, like this

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';


export default function SignIn() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
}
```

Then redirect to route:

```
navigate('/setup/location');
```